# how to create MySite & ContentType Hub in HNSC

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, my-site, host-named, hnsc

I know how to implement Content Type Hub & MySite as Path-Based site collections (PBSC), but in case of implementing Host-Named site collection (HNSC), I have doubt.

Can anyone guide me how to create a:

1. Content Type Hub site collection as a HNSC
2. MySite site collection as a HNSC

Comment: HNSC? Host name Site Collection?

Comment: yes, u r correct

Answer (score 1):

As mysites use self service site creation to automatically create sites when a user first navigates to them, it is not recommended to use Host Named Site Collections for user's mysites.
This is because you either need to pre-create all mysites (and then manually create sites for new users) using powershell, or use custom code to manage the provisioning process. This could quickly become a maintenance nightmare, and will have a higher cost of development and support.

Of course, you can use a combination of HNSC and PBSC. So you could, say, have My sites and your intranet in the same web application, and have the intranet use HNSC, while My sites use PBSC.

For a content type hub, you create the site as you would a team site using HNSC.

To create a Hostnamed Site Collection (applies to all, including Mysites and content type hubs), use the -HostHeaderWebApplication parameter of New-SPSite in PowerShell.

So, for example (let's say we have a contoso web application):

```
PS> New-SPSite 'http://intranet.contoso.com' -HostHeaderWebApplication 'http://contoso’ -Name 'Intranet'
```

There are more details (including a detailed example) at this [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952#section2) article.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: To make a clarification. You can create a My Site site collection as a HNSC. But, when the user's My Sites are provisioned the OOB provisioning will use the self-service site creation, which is Path-Based Site Collection (PBSC). If you want your My Sites to be 100% HNSC, then you will need to implement your own custom self-service site provisioning using HNSC. The following link clarifies things (especially the comments): http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/05/17/your-friendly-guide-to-host-named-site-collections-with-timo-heidschuster-sharepoint-solution-architect.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll add some clarification to my answer.  The MySite ref in your link were in the comments, and the MSFT even states: "Note: We do not recommend to pre-create my sites."